# Telegram Bot Java. 500 Request failed

Tags: java, telegram-bot

I write telegram bot via [rubenlagus](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots) api. Bot works well during certain time but then it stops responding to any requests. I use webhook connection. I had to install a full chained certificate to my server. I have next settings:

```
DefaultBotOptions options = new DefaultBotOptions();
    options.setMaxWebhookConnections(10);
    options.setMaxThreads(99);
    RequestConfig build = RequestConfig.copy(RequestConfig.custom().build())
            .setMaxRedirects(99)
            .build();
    options.setRequestConfig(build);
```

When i used getWebhookInfo via

> https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/getWebhookInfo

I recieved next response:

> {"ok":true,"result":{"url":"https:\myUrl.com","has_custom_certificate":false,
>   "pending_update_count"
>   :175,"last_error_date":1540816831,
>   "last_error_message":"Wrong response from the
>   webhook: 500 Request failed.","max_connections":10}}

It's look like this mistake occurs because of pending_update_count.
 How can i fix this error and how i can prevent it in a future?Thanks in advance.

**Update**

Sometimes i see this:

> {"ok":true,"result":{"url":"https:\myUrl.com","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":155,"last_error_date":1540923231,"last_error_message":"Read timeout expired","max_connections":99}}

I have this errors in my logs when bot sends response to user:

> TelegramApiException sendMyPhoto
>   org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: api.telegram.org:443 failed
>   to respond    at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:143)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
>     at
>   org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.DefaultAbsSender.sendHttpPostRequest(DefaultAbsSender.java:765)
>     at
>   org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.DefaultAbsSender.execute(DefaultAbsSender.java:226)

It seems like my server works incorrect. May it happens because of blocking telegram in Russia?